# interaction between seque and pmap

Tags: clojure

If I pmap a function onto a sequence how far ahead will the sequence be realised in parallel
If I have a single thread reading from a sequence being produced in parallel?

will this be different if I wrap it in a seque:

```
(seque 30 (pmap do-stuff (range 30000)))
```

vs.

```
(pmap do-stuff (range 30000))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pmap provides no guarantees of how far ahead it will read on it's *input* sequence - presumably, not too much farther than what it needs to do its calculation.

(seque 30 ...) will realize and cache up to 30 elements from pmap's *output* sequence. That must logically be at least the first 30 from the input sequence. How far beyond that I can't say without looking at the implementation of pmap, which you probably ought not to depend upon.

I'm curious why you need to know this. The details of when a function executes, particularly in a pmap, are something you usually *want* abstracted away. If it's curiosity, great. But if you're depending on some side effect of the do-stuff function, you're Doing It Wrong(tm).